# working with dates and returns

Tags: windows-7, windows, microsoft-excel-2010

I am doing a training matrix for my company where I enter the date of which a person has been trained and in the next cell automatically updates to the next time the employee has to be trained I have used the formular for example a2=a1+364 so this works fine, but when nothing is placed in a1 is there any way I can make it return blank or 0 instead of an odd date?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use [IF-formula](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/if.php) `=IF(A1="","",A1+364)` for example.